# Elasticsearch Transport Client Construction Issues

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch

I'm trying to implement a **Transport Client for Elasticsearch** following the example found here:

https://github.com/foundit/elasticsearch-transport-module-example

but the problem is that this example is outdated - most notably in its versions.

I have downloaded the example and have run it just fine. However, when trying to create my own maven project with dependencies for the updated versions of the same libraries, I've run into some problems that I fail to find an explanation for. Here are some snippets of code that might help:

**TransportTest.java**

```
package

import ...

public class TransportTest {
  public ESLogger logger = ESLoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass().getCanonicalName());

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TransportTest().run(args);
  }

  public void run(String[] args) {
    TransportCommandLineParameters parameters = new TransportCommandLineParameters().parse(args, logger);

    logger.info("Connection to cluster: [{}] using api key: [{}] in region [{}]", parameters.clusterId, parameters.apiKey, parameters.region);

    // Build the settings for our client.
    Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
            // Setting "transport.type" enables this module:
            .put("transport.type", "org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.FoundNettyTransport")
            // Create an api key via the console and add it here:
            .put("transport.found.api-key", parameters.apiKey)
            .put("cluster.name", parameters.clusterId)
            .put("client.transport.ignore_cluster_name", false)
            .put("client.transport.node_sampler_interval", "30s")
            .put("client.transport.ping_timeout", "30s")
            .build();

    // instantiate TransportClient and add ES to list of addresses to connect to
    Client client = new TransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9300));
    while(true) {
      try {
        logger.info("Getting cluster health...");
        ActionFuture<ClusterHealthResponse> healthFuture = client.admin().cluster().health(Requests.clusterHealthRequest());
        ClusterHealthResponse healthResponse = healthFuture.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        logger.info("Got cluster health response. Health: [{}]", healthResponse.getStatus());
      } catch(Throwable t) {
        logger.error("Unable to get cluster health response. Error message: [{}]", t.getMessage());
      }
      try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
      } catch(InterruptedException ie) { ie.printStackTrace(); }
    }

  }
}
```

**TransportCommandLineParameters.java**

```
package

import ...

@Parameters(commandDescription = "Elasticsearch Transport Module.", separators = "=")
public class TransportCommandLineParameters {
    @Parameter(names = {"-c", "--cluster-id"}, required = true, description = "Cluster id")
    public String clusterId;

    @Parameter(names = {"-a", "--api-key"}, required = true, description = "API key from the cluster ACL.")
    public String apiKey;

    @Parameter(names = {"-r", "--region"}, description = "Region (us-east-1/eu-west-1/...)")
    public String region = "us-east-1";

    public TransportCommandLineParameters parse(String[] args, ESLogger logger) {
        JCommander commander = new JCommander(this);
        try {
            commander.parse(args);
        } catch (ParameterException pe) {
            logger.error(pe.getMessage());
            commander.usage();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

**ERRORS**

```
java:[41,165] incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.net.InetAddress
**RESOLVED** java:[41,21] constructor TransportClient in class org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient cannot be applied to given types;
```

Any help resolving these errors would be appreciated. For one thing, I do not understand them and my research into these issues has brought me nothing useful to this specific situation of implementing a Transport Client for elasticsearch.

I'd like to note that both errors that are halting my project from being compiled both come from this line:

```
Client client = new TransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9300));
```

Again, any help resolving these errors would be appreciated, even if its knowing that there is a versioning issue already known. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you actually using Elastic Cloud? If so, you should follow the 2.x example: https://github.com/elastic/found-shield-example

Comment: No, I am not using Elastic Cloud...is this the issue with the first example I provided? I got it to run locally, with only an instance of plain-old ES running on my system. I never even got the above code to work, with the only differences from the original project being the dependencies being updated to support the newest versions of things.

Comment: Yes, the example that you found was for Elasticsearch 1.x. You should just reference the [documentation for the `TransportClient`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html#transport-client). Note that the code changed surrounding the `TransportClient` creation.

Comment: @pickypg thank you for pointing that detail out. So I fixed the first error, and will change the question to match but the second error, regarding the settings being interpreted as strings and incompatible with Inet addresses, still persists.

Comment: Can you show how you're trying to actually use it now? `new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300)` should probably do the trick (granted, when you switch to IP addresses you'll want to change to `InetAddress.getByName("1.2.3.4")`, but it's just a different string)

Comment: Sure thing. Here is the updated line of code:    `Client client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9300));`